# Stop caching for PHP 5.5.3 in MAMP

Tags: php, caching, mamp, php-5.5

Installed MAMP on a new Macbook with PHP 5.5.3.

Reload and refresh do nothing. Still nothing. Google around for a few minutes trying to find out what is wrong, come back and refresh. It works. What the heck?

I went into php.ini and disabled all the new OPcache and set the default cache time to 0. Added headers to the document to force no caching. Still same problem. What the heck is going on here?

The network tab is showing a HTTP 200 request, so any new HTML in the `index.php` file renders fine, but new PHP that needs to be rendered by the server is delayed and not rendered until some predetermined set of time passes that I don't know how to change. What's going on?

I checked this in Safari too so it is definitely a server thing that is keeping the file from rendering.

Interesting fact though, if I go into MAMP and change the PHP version to the old one (PHP 5.2 or something) it will render normally, with no "caching issues". Switch to PHP 5.5 and it hangs up. In the MAMP preferences caching options for 5.5 don't even exist and are automatically disabled.

Comment: I know that this is not a solution to your problem, but I'm personally not a big fan of MAMP, as, especially not when installing a custom stack is so easy - Here's a pretty swift guide to install a stack using homebrew: https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php

Comment: @mewm I didn't realise it could be so easy. Cheers! Used this to get going with nginx in just a few keystrokes. http://learnaholic.me/2012/10/10/installing-nginx-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 213, accepted):

**Disable OPCache**

MAMP now turns on OPCache by default, you can disable it by editing your php.ini file. Make sure you edit the correct php.ini.

I was running into the same problem myself. MAMP with PHP version 5.5.3 runs OPcache by default, but you can't turn it off in the GUI like you can with the older PHP version 5.2.17. You have to manually comment out all the OPcache lines at the end of the php.ini file (MAMP/bin/php/[version]/conf/php.ini) and make sure to stop and start the servers for the changes to take effect.

*I updated the URI, the changes can be reflective by also changing /conf/ under the php folder, but it seems MAMP will ignore these after restart*.

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it by commenting out the opcache lines. It's kind of puzzling that you have to go into the php.ini file to change this around. It's actually quite misleading, since it would seem like you have all the caching options given in the MAMP->Preferences drop-down box.

Comment: I'm wondering which part of their body MAMP creators were using to think while adding this "cool feature".

Comment: I thought I had something wrong with my ModX install, but no, your answer seems to have fixed it. Thanks. Further to that, I also reverted to the older version. It now runs much better.

Comment: Note that the `php.ini` file you want to edit is in /bin, *not* in /conf. My full path was `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini`.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report, hopefully they'll disable it by default in a future version: http://bugs.mamp.info/view.php?id=4296

Comment: @Husky +1 for note on folder location. I'm running latest MAMP to-date and the `conf/php.ini` refers to the one in the `bin` (not the `conf` at the root of the MAMP Application folder).

Comment: Within my php.ini, I can only see xcache and eaccelerator, I've tried searching for opcache etc..., however nothing shows up. I am using 5.4.4 and accessing the conf file (not the root location).

Comment: @Husky, I've edited the original post to point to this, as I noticed my original edit was only temporary.

Comment: I change the line
opcache.revalidate_freq=60

to

opcache.revalidate_freq=2

Comment: I don't normally post 'me too' comments, but this was easily the most frustrating problem I have ever encountered. How ridiculous that caching would be enabled by default!! I've been trying to debug my coding IDE settings for days before I discovered this!

Comment: What if you don't have MAMP?

Comment: FWIW I had to restart php-fpm before the change took effect. Restarting Apache was insufficient. Pulled my hair out for a while over this.

Comment: opcache.enable=0 did it for me

Answer (score 39):

I added **opcache_reset();** in my main PHP to stop this caching.

Removing it from `php5.5.3/conf/php.ini` did nothing for me.

**Edit**

Turns out there also is a `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini`. It
works if I comment it out there.

Comment: Commenting out OPcache in the /bin directory worked for me! Thanks for that!

Comment: Commenting OPcache in php.ini in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini` does nothing, but adding `opcache_reset();` to `index.php` worked.

Answer (score 29):

1) in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini 
2) set opcache.revalidate_freq=0
3) restart MAMP

Comment: This seems to work. I enjoyed implementing this solution better than commenting it all out. But is there a difference?

Comment: This is a troubled soul from the future, in 2022 with PHP 8 and MAMP 6.6 this still works great!

Answer (score 12):

Took me so long to figure out it was a MAMP problem! Why would OPcache be enabled by default-- and require php.ini tinkering to disable-- in an app that's supposed to be used for testing websites? Anyway, I read through this whole thread and tried the various solutions.

**Here are my notes on how each solution works and considerations for selecting a solution.**

Each solution works on its own; no need for redundancy.

---

## Webpage code solution

### opcache_reset();

```
<?php opcache_reset(); ?>
```

- Must be added in the webpage code.
- Forces all scripts to be reloaded.
- Works without restarting MAMP server.

## Server configuration solutions

**Important:** Use the `php.ini` file in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini` and not in
`/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.5.3/php.ini`. Adjust accordingly if you're using a different version of PHP.

### enable=0

```
[OPcache]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
enable=0
```

- Must be added under `[OPcache]` in `php.ini`.
- Disables OPcache.
- Requires MAMP server restart.

### opcache.revalidate_freq=0

```
[OPcache]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

- Modify `opcache.revalidate_freq` under `[OPcache]` in `php.ini`.
- Makes OPcache check for updates every 0 seconds instead of every 60 seconds.
- Requires MAMP server restart.

### Commenting out [OPcache]

```
;[OPcache]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
;opcache.memory_consumption=128
;opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
;opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
;opcache.revalidate_freq=60
;opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;opcache.enable_cli=1
```

- Comment out the entire `[OPcache]` section in `php.ini`.
- Removes OPcache from the PHP server.
- Requires MAMP server restart.

---

#### Considerations

Choose the webpage code solution if:

- You just need to force script refreshing for a particular project
- You don't want to restart the MAMP server
- You don't want to edit php.ini

Choose a server configuration solution if:

- You want to disable caching by default instead of having to do it in every project
- You're comfortable with editing php.ini

I personally prefer `enable=0` since it's the simplest solution for me, and I need caching disabled by default.

---

#### References

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php

Answer (score 4):

[image: MAMP 3.0.7.2 for OS X]

It looks like this is finally a GUI option. `MAMP 3.0.7.2 for Mac OS X`.

Comment: This doesn't disable OPCache apparently. Mine was still active even with this setting "off".

Answer (score 2):

It was painful spending around 1 hour trying to figure out what could it be.

I just added this at the end of the code and restart MAMP.

```
  opcache.revalidate_freq=0
  opcache_reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit "/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.5.3/php.ini", and search for [OPcache] and add this code under it directly:

```
opcache.enable=0
```

This will disable opcache in when use PHP in MAMP server.

Answer (score 2):

Oh man am I glad I found this thread! I was pulling my hair out! I just upgraded MAMP yesterday and didn't notice this caching issue until today while working on a project. Thought I was losing my mind. 
I just changed "/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.5.3/php.ini" very bottom of file opcache.enable=0

Answer (score 1):

This is also current in the Windows version of MAMP as well.

> C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.3\php.ini

It's listed at the very bottom of the file.

The other problem I found, was on a QNAP NAS TS-431. This caching is also enabled, and if you are working with dynamically changing files, or try to develop on it, you'll be ripping out your hair. As per the other comments, just comment it out. The setting is located in:

> Control Panel/Applications/Web Server/PHP.ini Maintenance.

Once again, you'll find the settings at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Open your Mamp panel
on the right top corner click "Preferences"
a pop will open ,there is a option to "off" the php cache.
It works like charm,No need to modify any other files.
[image]

Comment: @AbdurRehman, this is a valid answer to the original question. It is not asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

For those using MAMP `6.x` you have to disable the setting in the UI otherwise MAMP will overwrite your PHP files the next time you restart apache.

The setting is in the `PHP` setting as shown here:

[image]

Change the default `OPcache` setting to `off` and click `Save`. After saving restart the Apache service.

Comment: Any idea why is this on for a local dev app?

Comment: No, I can't see it being useful for local dev and should be disabled by default IMO.