# Laravel templates/controllers not updating on save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm running a Laravel 4 for a simple app on OS X.

Basically, changes to controllers and templates don't take effect for a long time after I save changes to those files. For example, I add a word to /app/views/index.blade.php, and don't see any change when constantly refreshing my browser for another minute or so. This makes iterative development understandably painful.

I have tried to `chmod 777 app/storage/` and all enclosed files, which has no effect. I have also verified this is not a browser cache issue, because it happens (a) in both Chrome and Safari, and (b) regardless of clearing the cache in those browsers. The problem still occurs even when the app is in "local" and not "production" mode.

I should mention that I am running an updated DP version of OS X 10.9 Mavericks. I can't imagine that would have any effect on Laravel, though.

#### Edit

I tried calling clearstatcache() in start.php to see if that had any effect, and the problem still remained.

Comment: If you rm -rf app/storage/cache/* does it work after that? This isn't a solution just want to see if it is actually Laravel.

Comment: I just did that, completely cleared caches in both browsers, and it still was not updated to what I changed it to until about a minute later.

Comment: I believe @autibyte should `rm -rf app/storage/views/*` rather than `app/storage/cache` to test if clearing the view cache works. Perhaps there's some issue where the File system can't update the view cache files after they are created. Make sure you `chmod -R 0777 app/storage` - you need the `-R` flag to make it recursive. Add in a `sudo` if you get permission errors when running `chmod`

Comment: @fideloper Thanks, but I tried removing `app/storage/views/` and the recursive `chmod` and the template didn't seem to update. I think this means that the problem is related to Laravel not realizing that the file is being updated, even though it is.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I did mean app/storage/views/*. If you did rm -rf app/storage/views/* then it is most likely not Laravel. That's where it caches views. So without that it has no way of "remembering" any view.

Comment: PHP 5.4+ ships with a web server. You might be able to use it to isolate an Apache issue. `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by uninstalling MAMP (the app package), then installing PHP, Nginx, and MySQL with homebrew. Now all of my templates update, yay! I am pretty sure that the problem lied with the combination of Apache and Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a laravel issues but a PHP 5.5.3 + MAMP. OP Cache is on by default. see this answer for more: [Stop caching for PHP 5.5.3 in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073270/stop-caching-for-php-5-5-3-in-mamp)

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue as as autibyte (note: also recently upgraded to Mavericks, but besides File System permissions not sure how this would be impacting) --- but my blade templates no longer seem to be updating. I've tried permissions + clearing out the views folder. No joy.

Comment: Checkout my answer, you might want to give Nginx a try.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and tried for almost 1 hour to fix the problem. All I did was to restart my computer and then everything worked like a charm  for me. Some times computers misbehave and the only solution is to restart or do a  cold boot.