# Why won't my data display on a server but will locally?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, server

I've built a forum in Laravel which comes with voting functions. The votes are +/-1. An attribute then counts all the 'upvotes' and 'downvotes' and displays them accordingly. All works fine locally with the votes displaying but as soon as I take it live on our server, the count doesn't seem to change.

The form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'votes.store']) !!}
{!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'value' => 'vote', 'name' => 'vote')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('task_id', $task->id) !!}
{{$task->upvotes}}
{!! $task->upvotes !!}
{!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i>', array('type' => 'submit', 'value' => 'downvote', 'name' => 'downvotes')) !!}
{{$task->downvotes}}
{!! Form::hidden('task_id', $task->id) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){
$this->validate($request, ['vote'])
        $input = new Votes($request->all());
//        $input->user()->associate($request->user());
//        $input->tasks()->associate($request->get('task_id'));
        if($request->get('downvotes')){
            $input->vote = -1;
        }
        else {
            $input->vote = 1;
        }
        $input->save();

//        dd($request->get('upvotes'));
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
        $categories = Category::findOrFail($id);
        $votes = Votes::whereTaskId($task);
        return view('tasks.show')->withTask($task)->withCategories($categories)->withVotes($votes);
    }
```

The model relations are fine and all is showing in the SQL DB. Here are the attributes too:

```
public function getUpvotesAttribute()
{
    return $this->votes->where('vote', 1)->count();
}

public function getDownvotesAttribute()
{
    return $this->votes->where('vote', -1)->count();
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what would be causing the problem and if I can provide any more details/clarify anything do let me know. I apologise if this is unclear.

**EDIT**
Here's a view of the DB table: [image: img]

Comment: Q: What do you mean by "locally"?  How exactly does it differ from the "live server"?  Are Laravel/PHP co-located on the same host in both the "local" and "live server"?  Q: Are you sure Laravel/PHP have successfully connected to mySql in the "live server" case?

Comment: @paulsm4 Apologies, might have been unclear. Locally I mean accessing via localhost:8000 and live server i mean via the actual url of the site. Does that make sense? Cheers, Joe.

Comment: @paulsm4 100% certain. All other data is showing and checking the database shows that the vote is being recorded.

Comment: @JoeWilliams Maybe it's a cache problem in your server. Have you configured cache?

Comment: @SantiagoMendozaRamirez thanks. I tried this but still nothing?

Comment: Q: Do *ANY* queries or updates work for "live server"?  Is the problem limited to "votes"?  Q: `$this->validate($request, ['vote'])` under `store()` is missing a semicolon in your post.  Is the actual code OK?  ALSO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150767/laravel-templates-controllers-not-updating-on-save

Comment: @paulsm4 The code works fine. The ; was missing only on here, rather than the actual file. I must have deleted it by accident here. I think the php.ini file issue may be as you suggest although I don't know where to find it on my server.