# PHP changes slow to refresh in browser

Tags: php, macos, bash

Ever since I added a .bash_profile on my Mac to point to a fresher version of PHP in MAMP, I've noticed my PHP changes take a long time to show in the browser localhost. It's absolutely killing me! I added the bash profile so I could install Laravel 4. Any fixes out there?

Comment: Do you mean that your pages are now slow to load, or that load times are fine but your changes don't appear in your browser for some time?

Comment: Load times are great. But changes take a few seconds to show. Refreshes don't speed anything up, it literally takes seconds, I can refresh a dozen times in a second and nothing happens.

Comment: hold shift and hit refresh

Comment: It's possible that the caching parameters in your new MAMP are different. You can possibly fix that in httpd.conf, or .htaccess. That's my best guess.

Comment: shift + CMD + R, didn't work. The problem feels like it's something in my PHP installation.

Comment: I don't know if the key command works, holding shift while clicking the actual button does a hard refresh, reloading all resources on the page even ones which were previously cached

Comment: After upgrading php to 5.5 in MAMP, for some obscure reason, OPCache is enabled by default. This makes the server return cached versions of pages instead of the newer versions (with your changes). I followed [instructions from this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19130992/1200166) to disable OPCache.

Answer (score 4):

Comment out the OPcache in your php.ini files.

/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.5.3/php.ini

```
[OPcache]
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so"
;  opcache.memory_consumption=128
;  opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
;  opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
;  opcache.revalidate_freq=60
;  opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;  opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Otherwise you can just set `opcache.enable` to 0, that'll also disable the opcache.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. The problem with my slow PHP was the version I was using, 5.5.3. Once I switched MAMP to 5.2.17 everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try Preferences -> General, then set PHP-Cache to "Off"