# OS X 10.8 browsers not reflecting code changes on local development

Tags: caching, browser, mamp

I just purchased a MacBook air and for some reason whenever I'm testing a project locally (on MAMP) I'm forced to refresh the page about 6 or 7 times for the changes that I've made in the text editor to be reflected in the browser. Originally I thought that this was because I wasn't using private browsing. So, I switched to chrome incognito. That didn't work. So, then I switched to firefox and then opera. That, too didn't work. These problems happen both with backend and front end code. It's very strange it makes the task of local development very very difficult and time consuming. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using MAMP 2.2 with php 5.5 enabled? Then it's likely that it's because OPcache is enabled per default. See here: [Stop caching for PHP 5.5.3 in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073270/stop-caching-for-php-5-5-3-in-mamp)