# MAMP server issue

Tags: php, mamp

I am using MAMP and Codeigniter, the issue I am having is every time I change the controller or model, I have to restart the server to get the changes. Is there some kind of cache going on?

Comment: By the way, I am using chrome, and I'm sure the cache is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

**What you need to do**,

The modification is simple, its just a change to the MAMP preferences.

1. Open MAMP
2. Click the “Preferences” button or select “Preferences” from the MAMP
   menu
3. Click on “PHP” in the tab-bar if its not already selected
4. Change the “Cache” dropdown to be “––” so that no caching extension
   is used
5. Click “OK” to save the changes
6. Restart MAMP (click “Stop Servers” and then “Start Servers” once
   they’ve stopped)

Above is extracted from [here](http://top-frog.com/2011/03/14/beware-mamps-default-caching-settings/).

Also see below

[How to prevent http file caching in Apache httpd (MAMP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532636/prevent-http-file-caching-in-apache-httpd-mamp)

[Stop caching for PHP 5.5.3 in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073270/stop-caching-for-php-5-5-3-in-mamp)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, when I use version 5.2.17, it works, 5.5.3 dose not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Please see the last link

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.