# Symfony2 everything cached on dev?

Tags: symfony, caching, mamp

If I change something in a controller I have to wait like 40 seconds until i see the changes. Seems like Symfony is caching but i thought it is not when im using web/app_dev.php/ ??

Did i do something wrong with the Symfony installation??

I googled for this but i only find to put following into config_dev.yml

```
twig:
    cache:  false
```

And now when i change something within template files it is shown directly. But when i change something in the controller i still have to wait 40 seconds... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out this is not Symfony caching the files. It is mamp php 5.5.3 ... see:

[Stop caching for PHP 5.5.3 in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073270/stop-caching-for-php-5-5-3-in-mamp)

Comment: You can accept your own answer if your problem is solved, you may have to wait several days.