# php caching - Cannot seem to disable opcache in MAMP Pro

Tags: php, caching, mamp, mamp-pro, opcache

This has come up a number of times in other threads, and I've tried every solution that I found with no luck.

Running MAMP Pro v6.6.3, and the opcache module is running wild. All my php pages are bing cached seemingly individually, meaning that I can have multiple versions of edits across any number of pages. Not great for productivity!

Even waiting a few minutes doesn't seem to clear any kind of cache - the changes seem to be indefinite, and update on in the browser only when they feel like it.

I have:

- Commented out all opcache options in php.ini via the *File > Open Template* option, and also edited the same in **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php[version]/conf/php.ini**, saving and restarting MAMP each time
- Changed `opcache.enable=1` to `opcache.enable=0` in php.ini via the *File > Open Template* option, and also edited the same in **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php[version]/conf/php.ini**, saving and restarting MAMP each time
- Changed `opcache.revalidate_freq=2` (or sometimes `opcache.revalidate_freq=1`) to `opcache.revalidate_freq=0` in php.ini via the *File > Open Template* option, and also edited the same in **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php[version]/conf/php.ini**, saving and restarting MAMP each time
- Uncommented `opcache.validate_timestamps=1` in php.ini via the *File > Open Template* option, and also edited the same in **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php[version]/conf/php.ini**, saving and restarting MAMP Pro each time
- Installed and tried various versions of php throughout 5, 7 and 8, and then repeated all of the above (or the version-appropriate equivalent of) for each php.ini for that version.
- Checked my laptop where MAMP Pro is also installed where there were previously no issues - now somehow it’s happening on there too?! I can't think of any sensible reason this would be. I don't use the laptop that often and no updates have been made.
- Tried different browsers, thinking it might be a browser cache problem. It’s not. This is occurring on browsers that I’ve never even used for this project before, and the cached version is being served on the first/initial page load.

I am also finding that this is continuing to happen even if phpinfo() seems to show opcache as being disabled.

“**Cache module to speed up execution**” is set to “**off**” in the php settings via the MAMP Pro interface.

Other threads with similar issues:

- [Turn off Caching in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245321/turn-off-caching-in-mamp)
- [MAMP time between seeing live changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079089/mamp-time-between-seeing-live-changes)

Can anybody please offer some insight? Is there something that I haven’t tried yet, or have failed to see?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are testing `phpinfo()` in a browser and _not_ on the CLI?

Comment: You should confirm that its not a browser cache problem by clearing the browser caches.  ctrl+shift+del on firefox and chrome.

Comment: @chrisHass, yes I can confirm I’m testing phpinfo() in a browser.

Comment: @RohitGupta it’s definitely not a browser cache issue as I have cleared my browser cache many many times

Comment: Hey @alexconnor7, Did you manage to fix this? Having the same issue this morning after it being fine before. All Cache is disabled but still changes still don't reflect

Comment: @AdamCollingburn the issue appeared to resolve itself after I cleared the WordPress cache from the dashboard as well a few times. I typically use WP Super Cache. If you're using WP and also a caching plugin, try mashing that for a while. Hope you can sort it, it's a frustrating issue!

Comment: Thanks - for me, the new version of MAMP Pro auto copies the repo into htdocs directory. Changing the root directory again worked for me