# Laravel caching old controllers MAMP

Tags: caching, controller, laravel-4, mamp

I have a Laravel application that refuses to acknowledge controller changes even if the controller doesn't exist anymore!

**Using MAMP PRO 5.5.3 and Laravel 4.1**
with
**/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php**

I have followed these instructions
[Stop caching for PHP 5.5.3 in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073270/stop-caching-for-php-5-5-3-in-mamp/22530388#22530388)

I have deleted the view storage in Laravel.

There was mention of adding - opcache_reset(); in my bootstrap/autoload.php

http://laravel.io/forum/02-06-2014-laravel-and-view-caching-in-development-cant-see-changes-right-away

But not sure how and where you do you do that, I tried but just got an error

Call to undefined function opcache_reset()

The caching still continues!

Despite the controller having been deleted 2 hours ago (to prove controller not being called), it is still showing the page with an imaginary controller.

It's driving me insane.

Any help really appreciated.

Further to this the **route** file is refusing to accept **UserController**

```
Route::get('register', 'UserController@getRegister');
```

Giving this error

```
 .....controllers/UserControllerb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

UserControllerb.php doesn't exist and was not asked for ?! but the route is wrongly looking for it

When I try this

```
 Route::get('register', 'UserControllerb@getRegister');
```

Rightly give this error

```
Class UserControllerb does not exist
```

So the route has been cached  (a previous back-up removed days ago)

I have tried to use composer which decides it doesn't want to work and no-one seems to know the solution for either problem.

[Laravel composer signal "11" error symfony osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542294/laravel-composer-signal-11-error-symfony-osx/22640572?noredirect=1#22640572)

Huge kudos to anyone who can solve this.

Comment: It seems to be this particular file only now! I have simply made it to ....Controller1.php and the changes are taking effect. The Controller ghost in the machine can still be called from the route, very strange!!

Comment: did you try running `composer dump-autoload` in terminal ?

Comment: yep,tried that a while back but no luck. It seems to work now with other named controllers but one ghost controller exists. I have solved this by just renaming the route and adding a new controller for this.