# Laravel composer signal "11" error symfony osx

Tags: macos, symfony, laravel, composer-php

Anything I try to execute in Laravel, even minor files locally gives this message in composer:

[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The process has been signaled with signal "11".

Using OSX 10.7.5

Any help appreciated, as always.

For example :

```
composer update
```

typed in terminal retrieves the error message above

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't precise. When I try to add or update a laravel component/app from terminal with composer.

Comment: [Signal 11](http://www.bitwizard.nl/sig11/) is a "segmentation fault", which means that a program accessed a memory location that was not assigned. Since you're using Symfony Process, I guess it's not PHP that crashes here, but the program you're executing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I eventually solved this by employing a freelancer who was excellent and very knowledgeable.

- First needed to update OSX with Maverick (free) - (I had to change my hard drive to do this!)
- Then needed to download xcode
- Composer should then function, you may need a new installation of laravel

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Yes but it does with OSX. Anyway, that was with Maverick.

Comment: Unless your PHP is installed by xCode, which lead to work by reinstalling and upgrading PHP together.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check your composer cache folder has the right permissions for all files and folders.

If you ever ran composer as sudo or root then these cache folders could have the wrong root permissions.

Look at all the files and folders inside:

```
ll ~/.composer/cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper permissions to write files in `app/storage` directory. And you can always use the following method of installation.

1. `cd /your/app/directory`
2. `git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git .`
3. `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error due to circular dependency on `AppServiceProvider` (when 2 services depend on each other). As the error does say much it took me a loooong time figure it out :/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Reinstall or upgrade PHP (Cli)
- Make sure your `.composer` directory permission

This error message from laravel artisan is caused by Composer command error, you can try the same way from using command like:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

It should also cause error relating from `aristan optimize` command which be trigger from `post-update-cmd"` in `composer.json`.

In my case, the error is segment fault via Cygwin PHP so that I change to use XAMPP PHP to run it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run thin command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: there is a typo. use this one: `composer dump-autoload`