# PHPStorm PHP file changes change rarely in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, phpstorm

PHPStorm 7.0
MAMP 2.2 (Not Pro)
Chrome broweser

After I did some changes to my PHP code in PHPStorm IDE I hit the "Reload this page" button in Chrome.
Some times I have to hit the button about 5 times or quit Chrome and
turn on Chrome again to see the changes I did in PHPStorm.
Are there any ways to fix this issue?

Comment: Try to disable your browser cache. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Comment: If this does not help disable the php cache. But this depends on you t development environment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073270/stop-caching-for-php-5-5-3-in-mamp

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to disable browser cache

Comment: Thanks. I commented out all the OPCache lines at the end of the php.ini file.  PATH: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini Work well.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you! As my Answer solves your problem i added my comments as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disable your browser cache.

[Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

If this does not help disable the php cache. But this depends on your development environment.

[Stop caching for PHP 5.5.3 in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073270/stop-caching-for-php-5-5-3-in-mamp)